# Visualising JSON using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have JSON data (see below) which is generated by a probe (well 22 of them in fact) that does an ICMP test every 5 minutes.

I'm struggling to find a way to plot data of the following format:

```
{"fw": 5010, "mver": "2.2.0", "lts": 3, "dst_name": "X.X.X.X", "af": 4, "dst_addr": "X.X.X", "src_addr": "10.0.0.4", "proto": "ICMP", "ttl": 246, "size": 48, "result": [{"rtt": 13.046654}, {"rtt": 12.811082}, {"rtt": 12.768602}, {"rtt": 12.740659}, {"rtt": 12.832452}], "dup": 0, "rcvd": 5, "sent": 5, "min": 12.740659, "max": 13.046654, "avg": 12.8398898, "msm_id": 25610869, "prb_id": 1000370, "timestamp": 1598518978, "msm_name": "Ping", "from": "Y.Y.Y.Y", "type": "ping", "group_id": 25610869, "step": 300, "stored_timestamp": 1598519029}
```

What i would like is essentially a line per probe (ID is unique) with "avg" latency.

I'm trying something along the lines of:

```
FILE = open("/home/sngx/Documents/PythonProjects/ripe_data.json")
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 20)
output = pd.read_json(FILE)
output = output.rename(index=output["timestamp"])
measurement = output["msm_id"]
data = output[["avg"]]
data.groupby(["avg"])
data.plot()
plt.title(f"RIPE Measurement Data {measurement}")
plt.ylabel("Latency - msec")
plt.xlabel("Date and Time")
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.  `json_normalize()` and `pprint()`are good for working with nested dictionaries.

```
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint

# import data
df = pd.json_normalize(data)

# convert timestamp
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='s')

# select columns of interest
df = df.filter(['timestamp', 'prb_id', 'avg'])

# re-shape (timestamps as row labels, probe id's as column labels)
df = df.set_index(['timestamp', 'prb_id' ]).squeeze().unstack(level='prb_id')

print(df)

prb_id                1000000   1000370
timestamp                              
2020-08-27 09:02:58  13.83989  12.83989
2020-08-27 09:02:59  13.83989  12.83989
```

DISCUSSION:

- The data frame may have NaN values, which means there are 'holes' in the data.  For example, if you have 10 unique time stamps and 5 probes, then `df` will have 50 entries.
- But what if there were only 45 observations in the original data?  You'll get 5 NaNs.
- If you plot a data frame with NaNs, you'll get discontinuities in the resulting plots.  Useful to see if you weren't expecting them.
- Or, you could re-sample the data (aggregate into 15-second, or 1-minute buckets).

Docs here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

Sample data

- I modified original post's data to get 4 records:

```
data = [
    {"fw": 5010, "mver": "2.2.0", "lts": 3, "dst_name": "X.X.X.X", "af": 4, "dst_addr": "X.X.X", "src_addr": "10.0.0.4", "proto": "ICMP", "ttl": 246, "size": 48, "result": [{"rtt": 13.046654}, {"rtt": 12.811082}, {"rtt": 12.768602}, {"rtt": 12.740659}, {"rtt": 12.832452}], "dup": 0, "rcvd": 5, "sent": 5, "min": 12.740659, "max": 13.046654, "avg": 12.8398898, "msm_id": 25610869, "prb_id": 1000370, "timestamp": 1598518978, "msm_name": "Ping", "from": "Y.Y.Y.Y", "type": "ping", "group_id": 25610869, "step": 300, "stored_timestamp": 1598519029},
    {"fw": 5010, "mver": "2.2.0", "lts": 3, "dst_name": "X.X.X.X", "af": 4, "dst_addr": "X.X.X", "src_addr": "10.0.0.4", "proto": "ICMP", "ttl": 246, "size": 48, "result": [{"rtt": 13.046654}, {"rtt": 12.811082}, {"rtt": 12.768602}, {"rtt": 12.740659}, {"rtt": 12.832452}], "dup": 0, "rcvd": 5, "sent": 5, "min": 12.740659, "max": 13.046654, "avg": 13.8398898, "msm_id": 25610869, "prb_id": 1000000, "timestamp": 1598518978, "msm_name": "Ping", "from": "Y.Y.Y.Y", "type": "ping", "group_id": 25610869, "step": 300, "stored_timestamp": 1598519030},

    {"fw": 5010, "mver": "2.2.0", "lts": 3, "dst_name": "X.X.X.X", "af": 4, "dst_addr": "X.X.X", "src_addr": "10.0.0.4", "proto": "ICMP", "ttl": 246, "size": 48, "result": [{"rtt": 13.046654}, {"rtt": 12.811082}, {"rtt": 12.768602}, {"rtt": 12.740659}, {"rtt": 12.832452}], "dup": 0, "rcvd": 5, "sent": 5, "min": 12.740659, "max": 13.046654, "avg": 12.8398898, "msm_id": 25610869, "prb_id": 1000370, "timestamp": 1598518979, "msm_name": "Ping", "from": "Y.Y.Y.Y", "type": "ping", "group_id": 25610869, "step": 300, "stored_timestamp": 1598519029},
    {"fw": 5010, "mver": "2.2.0", "lts": 3, "dst_name": "X.X.X.X", "af": 4, "dst_addr": "X.X.X", "src_addr": "10.0.0.4", "proto": "ICMP", "ttl": 246, "size": 48, "result": [{"rtt": 13.046654}, {"rtt": 12.811082}, {"rtt": 12.768602}, {"rtt": 12.740659}, {"rtt": 12.832452}], "dup": 0, "rcvd": 5, "sent": 5, "min": 12.740659, "max": 13.046654, "avg": 13.8398898, "msm_id": 25610869, "prb_id": 1000000, "timestamp": 1598518979, "msm_name": "Ping", "from": "Y.Y.Y.Y", "type": "ping", "group_id": 25610869, "step": 300, "stored_timestamp": 1598519030},
]
```

Comment: WOW, thank you! 
Almost there i think. The only problem is i'm seeing a lot of NaN data:
2020-08-27 09:02:43      NaN      NaN      NaN  1.682958       NaN      NaN  ...      NaN      NaN       NaN        NaN      NaN      NaN

Comment: I added a Discussion section to the reponse; it was too long for a comment

Comment: Ah, i think i know why it's like this. Although probes run all at the same time at 5 min interval. Their start time wasn't identical. There maybe difference in a few seconds in between. So timestamp for probe X will not be the same as for probe Y and so forth. So i guess i'll have to use plot that supports NaN handling and filling empty data? Or is there another way?
thank you for your help so far :)

Comment: I think Matplotlib has sensible defaults for missing data, so you could start with that.  Here is more info: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/visualization.html#plotting-with-missing-data

Comment: Also, here is a good reference for the complex but useful Matplotlib package: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.00-introduction-to-matplotlib.html

Comment: There is a lot more to say about plotting data frames with NaNs -- please consider opening a new question, if you're interested.

Comment: Sorry, last one. Any way of adding a label to data for example describing a probe which is not part of a data set? 
E.g: probe_id 1234 - "ISP A"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220635/discussion-between-jsmart-and-sngx).